# Select WORD under cursor

Tags: replace

I know that * selects the word under the cursor, but what if I want to actually select a WORD ?

Just to be clear, I would then like to use the selection for a replace, something like `:%s//foo/g`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would then like to use the selection for a replace, something like :%s//foo/g

```
:%s/^R^A/foo/g
```

See `:h c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A`

Comment: I always forget about these command line mapping but that is indeed the best way to go

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the help topic [`:h <cWORD>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3ccWORD%3e). When you combine it with [`:h expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29) it allows you to get the WORD under your cursor. You can try this command to understand how it works:

```
:echo expand('<cWORD>')
```

Now if you want to have for example `<leader>*` to work as `*` but with WORDs you could use the following mapping which will use `expand('<cWORD>')` as the current search pattern:

```
nnoremap <leader>* :execute '/' . expand('<cWORD>')<CR>
```

If you want to use that directly in a substitution you could do something like this:

```
execute 's/' . expand('<cWORD>') . '/foo/g'
```

See [`:h execute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#execute%28%29) if you are not familiar with this way of building commands.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to map your `*` key in visual mode to make it search for the selection:

```
" search visual selection
vnoremap * y/\V<C-R>=escape(@",'/\')<CR><CR>
```

Then, you can do `viW*` to effectively search the WORD under the cursor.

---

Also, you could use a map to quickly start replacing the current selection:

```
nnoremap gr :s/<c-r>///g<left><left>
```